# Question on functions on a torus in Vlasov-Poisson system

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology

I am studying the Vlasov-Poisson system on the threedimensional torus. In a paper by Rein and Rendall (https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9306021), they define a matter distribution on the phase space $\mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R^3}$ that is homogeneous in $x$ and locally isotropic in $v$,
\begin{align}
f(t,x,v) = H \left(a^2(t) \big| v - \frac{\dot{a}(t)}{a(t)} x\big|^2\right),
\end{align}
where $H\in C^1_c(\mathbb{R})$ is a nonnegative function. However, they are working on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Can this $f$ also be defined on the torus $\mathbb{T}^3\times \mathbb{R^3}$ or would it need to be periodic in $x$? If so, is there a way to find a similar $f$ that is periodic?

EDIT: Let me clarify the question: in their paper they prove global existence of classical solutions to the Vlasov-Poisson equation for deviations from a homogeneous state in an expanding setting. The way they define $f$ is exactly this spatially homogeneous state. They show that $f$ is a solution to (VPS) if $a(t)$ satisfies
\begin{align}
\ddot{a}(t) + \frac{4\pi}{3} a^{-1}(t) = 0
\end{align}
which describes homogeneous and isotropic dust solutions in general relativity in general; also on the torus. This made me think about whether one can use the same background to find the same equation for $a$, or if one needs an updated $f$ that still yields a constant density distribution and the same equation for $a$ on the torus. Unfortunately, I am not really used to working on a torus.

Comment: What would the quantity $|v - \alpha x|^2$ even mean for general $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, and $x \in \mathbb{T}^3$?  The torus isn't equipped with a notion of scalar multiplication, nor is there a well-defined norm on it.

Comment: What do you mean? I can define Sobolev norms on the torus.

Comment: For functions defined on the torus, sure, there are things like $L^2$ norms, etc because there is a vector space structure.  The torus is a group at best.  There is not a well-defined norm on the set $\mathbb{T}^3$ itself, so how can you hope to use your $f$ as is on the torus?